# Android device monitor JRE/JDK error

Tags: android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I get an error on my android studio 3.0.1 on my 64 bit windows 10 laptop. Have kept the settings of Android SDK to use its own JRE. But I am still getting the following error:

"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Monitor. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: ANDROID FOLDER PATH"

Rgds

Comment: have you got any solution? @Scyber

Answer (score 6):

Easiest solution is to Copy the JRE from Android studio and paste it to Monitor's location.

in my case i copied *JRE folder* 
from **C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio**
to **C:\SDK\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64**

Answer (score 1):

search your computer for file called `javaw.exe`, copy its url.

For example mine was in `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.8f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\jre\bin`

Then, in `Control Panel -> System ->Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables`, under System variables, click on the `path` and click edit.

[image]

Paste the url into the free slot and save everything.

After this, Monitor will launch correctly.

What we've done is specify yet another folder where important files are located.  They are searched one after another by Monitor, until it finds `javaw.exe` in that last url we've just added.

**Edit**

Maybe it will make sense to only supply part of the path, for example:
`Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.8f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK`